# Unable to install @angular/cli - what can I do?

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install

I am trying to install @angular/cli using npm. But it always gets stuck while downloading the package `chokidar`:

[image: console screenshot]

What can I do about it?

Answer (score 0):

Stop the installation, use *npm* to uninstall what was already installed. Check that is was done, if needed delete manually. Don't be behind a firewall and make sure your **trusted sites* are up-to-date and nothing is blocking packages you need to install.